# Simple rollover effect using picture source srcset with next-gen images like .webp

Tags: html, image, rollover, srcset

Updating code and optimizing site speed so trying to change this simple html rollover effect:

`<img src="img1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='img2.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='img1.jpg'">`

To something along the lines of this:

```
<picture>
<source srcset="img1.webp" type="image/webp" onmouseover="this.src='img2.webp'" onmouseout="this.src='img1.webp'">
<source srcset="img1.jpg" type="image/jpeg"  onmouseover="this.src='img2.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='img1.jpg'">
<img src="img1.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='img2.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='img1.jpg'">
</picture>
```

I didn't really expect the latter to work, but am mentally blocked as to the correct approach for this basic effect so the browser will access the appropriate image format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming one is already using Modernizr js, here is one possible solution using CSS & HTML:

```css
.webp .rollover{
  background:url("/img3/img1.webp")
  }
  
.webp .rollover:hover{
  background:url("/img3/img2.webp")
  }
  
.no-webp .rollover{
  background:url("/img3/img1.jpg")
  }
  
.no-webp .rollover:hover{
  background:url("/img3/img2.jpg")
  }
```

```html
<div class="rollover"></div>
```

I know there are other solutions as well, but this one worked for me.

One downside of this approach is there is a lag while img2.xxx is loaded 'onHover'.  However, this also means img2 is not explicitly 'preloaded', hence speeding up overall page download time.  (One could finesse this too).